# Missing Core Bundle Extension - Magento Integrity Scan?

Tags: magento2.4, magento-core

I am missing a core module bundled with magento 2.4.X

I have failed to find anything that magento may offer like an integrity scan or verify core modules command that would let me resolve this issue in a simple manner. Due to it being a CBE, I am also not finding a composer or other command that will attain, in my case, the 2FA extension. I hope I can keep this generalized enough to help others by asking if there is a way to do an integrity check of magento core modules that leads to a repair?

My specific case is the 2FA module missing, where the Magento documentation declares the installation step is "you should already have this":

> The 2FA extension installs when you install or upgrade to Magento Open Source or Commerce 2.4.X. The extension installs like a Core Bundled Extension (CBE).
> *https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/security/two-factor-authentication.html*

Answer (score 1):

Check your core `config.xml` file in the app folder and enable the extension `'Magento_Bundle' => 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best resources are the Relese Notes (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/bk-release-notes.html) for each Magento version you are planning to upgrade to. This includes the 2FA indications for [2.4.0 version](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/release-notes-2-4-0-open-source.html) when this was introduced. Understanding what has changed in a specific version will avoid many of the post upgrade problems.

Also, you can always refer the Packages list (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/packages-open-source.html) where you can double check the dependencies.